# How to find the correct row with a specific name and click the remove button on the found row? Selenium+Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, testng, ui-automation

## **How to find the correct row with a specific name and click the remove button on the found row?**

Website: http://opencart.abstracta.us/

The test added two items to Cart, it's looks like: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwiuL.jpg)

I’d like to delete the iMac item and check that this item was deleted

**How can I find the row with the name iMac and delete the iMac item?**

```
@Test
    public void removeProductFromCart(){
        String productName = "Samsung SyncMaster 941BW";
        String text = "iMac";
        SearchResults searchResults = homePage.searchProducts(productName);
        searchResults.addItemToCart(); // "Samsung SyncMaster 941BW" added to Cart
        searchResults = homePage.searchProductsEnter(text);
        searchResults.addItemToCart(); // "iMac" added to Cart
        var cartPage = homePage.goToShoppingCart();
        cartPage.removeItem(text);
        Assert.assertFalse(cartPage.isProductTextListed(text), "error");
    }
```

I wrote two methods:

```
By baseTable = By.xpath("//div[@class='table-responsive']/table[@class='table table-bordered']");
By tableRows = By.xpath("//div[@class='table-responsive']/table/tbody/tr");
By productNamesInCart = By.xpath("//div[@class='table-responsive']/table/tbody/tr/td[2]");
By removeBtn = By.xpath("//button[@type='button' and @class='btn btn-danger']");

  public void clickRemoveBtn(){
         driver.findElement(removeBtn).click();
  }

  public void removeItem(String text){
        WebElement table = driver.findElement(baseTable);
        List<WebElement> rows = table.findElements(tableRows);
        for(WebElement row : rows){
            List<WebElement> cols = row.findElements(productNamesInCart);
            for(WebElement col :cols){
                if(col.getText().equals(text)){
                    clickRemoveBtn();
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

So we found a table, after we found a row with the name iMac I guess. But the clicked button is not in the found row.

**I don't know how to find the correct row with name iMac and click the remove button on the found row.**

- *removeBtn* locator looking for all buttons on every row. [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUXvg.jpg)
- *productNamesInCart* locator looking for all names as well.[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1hfE.jpg)
- xpath for every row //div[@class='table-responsive']/table/tbody/tr

Assert methods:

```
public boolean isProductTextListed(String text){
        return checkProductNames(text) !=null;
    }
public Object checkTextNames(String text){
        List<WebElement> itemNames = driver.findElements(productNamesInCart);
        for(WebElement itemName : itemNames){
            String name = itemName.getText();
            //System.out.println(name);
            if(name.equals(text)){
                return itemName;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the purposes of testing, I created an xpath that finds the table in question:

```
//div[@id='content']//form//table[@class='table table-bordered']
```

I'm not a fan of looping if I can avoid it. Causes clutter. If we know the text of the item we want to find, and we know that there will only be one such item, we can just find that item on the list specifically, like so:

```
//div[@id='content']//form//table[@class='table table-bordered']//a[text()='iMac']
```

Now we just need to go 'up' the hierarchy to our table data, and then 'down' our hierarchy to the button we want.

```
//div[@id='content']//form//table[@class='table table-bordered']//a[text()='iMac']/ancestor::td//following-sibling::td//button[@data-original-title='Remove']
```

Ancestor takes us 'up' a level, following-sibling takes us 'across' a level (four levels really), and //button takes us down to the remove button.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it looks like hard coding that's not a good practice. The name of the item might be changed in test methods.